# Find message attached to Bitcoin transaction?

Tags: transactions, transaction-id

Given a txid, can I find out the message/comment the transaction was attached with by the sender?

Answer (score 3):

Transactions do not have comments attached to them. Any comments are local to a person's wallet only. They are not broadcast to the network nor are they actually attached to a transaction. So you cannot find the message or comment that a person assigned to a transaction in their wallet.

Comment: I was thinking if OP meant s.th. like OP_Return in a v_out, where in a tx you could use this to place messages in the blockchain? Where one wouldn't go the usual OP_DUP, OP_HASH, OP_DATA ..., OP_EQUALVERIFY, OP_CHECKSIG as in std P2PKH tx.

Comment: People don’t do that.